# How set opacity to image but not to text on recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, xml

What I want is: A RecyclerVIew that in each cell shows me an ImageView and a TextView, and I want to set opacity to that ImageView but not to the TextView.

The problem is: When I set the alpha (opacity) to the ImageView, the TextView is also affected.

My question is: How do I achieve opacity to the ImageView without affecting the TextView?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/beers"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"/> --- (Opacity)

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idNombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Nombre"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Did you tried to set by code? Like: idImagen.setAlpha(0.5f);

Comment: How did you know that the text view alpha is changing too? is it from the UI? what happens when you log getAlpha for your textview?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with setAlpha and the TextView seems affected as well. I can see that the TextView is affected when I run the app on my phone